# Xamarin.Forms Android FileProvider: GrantWriteUriPermission not always working

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin, android-fileprovider

I want to **edit** files from the internal storage of my Xamarin.Forms Android app in third party apps, for example fill out form elements in a PDF file or edit a .docx file.

With my implementation the file gets correctly opened in the external app, but in certain apps it is opened **read-only**. 
Adobe Acrobat and Microsoft Word open the files read-only, while other apps like Google Docs are able to write back into the file.
(I am using Microsoft Word with a valid Office365 subscription).

My FileProvider in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" 
          android:authorities="xamarintestapp.xamarintestapp.fileprovider" 
          android:grantUriPermissions="true" 
          android:exported="false">
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"     
               android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
</provider>
```

filepaths.xml:

```
<paths>
        <files-path name="files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Via the Xamarin.Forms DependencyService I am starting a Activity and pass the content uri to launch the external app:

```
public void OpenFile(string fileName)
{
    string auth = "xamarintestapp.xamarintestapp.fileprovider";
    string mimeType = Android.Webkit.MimeTypeMap.Singleton.GetMimeTypeFromExtension(Android.Webkit.MimeTypeMap.GetFileExtensionFromUrl(fileName.ToLower()));
    if (mimeType == null)
        mimeType = "*/*";

    var file = new Java.IO.File(Path.Combine(Forms.Context.FilesDir.Path, fileName));
    Android.Net.Uri uri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Forms.Context, auth, file);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
    intent.SetDataAndType(uri, mimeType);
    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission | ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission);
    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.NoHistory);

    // Trying to allow writing to the external app ...
    var resInfoList = Forms.Context.PackageManager.QueryIntentActivities(intent, PackageInfoFlags.MatchDefaultOnly);
    foreach (var resolveInfo in resInfoList)
    {
        var packageName = resolveInfo.ActivityInfo.PackageName;
        Forms.Context.GrantUriPermission(packageName, uri, ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission | ActivityFlags.GrantPrefixUriPermission | ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
    }

    Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this simply not possible?

Comment: If one app behaves like expected and two not then why do you think you are to blame? Try other extensions and other apps. Try those two apps without file provider.

Comment: I have tried both apps without the FileProvider (copying the files to external storage and opening them from there - the files are opened writable then). 

I tried ContentProvider and DocumentProvider as well, with the same result, some apps open the files read-only while others don't, I'm curious why...

Comment: Based on your code like `Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);`, you're actually developing a Xamarin.Forms solution, not the Xamarin.Android, am I right? And your problem is about the write permission on other platforms like UWP, not on Android Platform?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you are right, I am developing a Xamarin.Forms app and implement the OpenFile Method in the platform-specific projects via the Xamarin.Forms DependencyService. I updated my question accordingly. My OpenFile implementation under UWP works, but I'm having trouble under Android, haven't tried iOS yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation I can confirm that this seems to be an issue of the app receiving my intent (e.g. Microsoft Word).

When I start a EDIT intent instead of a VIEW intent as in

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionEdit);
```

the file is opened with write access in certain apps (xodo pdf, google docs) but read-only in other apps (Adobe PDF Reader, Microsoft Word) so I'm assuming these apps do not implement receiving an edit intent correctly.